# Ruby Array concat versus + speed?

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance

I did small performance test of Ruby's array `concat()` vs `+` operation and `concat()` was way too fast.

I however am not clear on why `concat()` is so fast?

Can anyone help here?

This is the code I used:

```
t = Time.now
ar = []
for i in 1..10000
ar = ar + [4,5]
end
puts "Time for + " + (Time.now - t).to_s 


t = Time.now
ar = []
for i in 1..10000
ar.concat([4,5])
end
puts "Time for concat " + (Time.now - t).to_s
```

Comment: FYI :) http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html

Answer (score 48, accepted):

According to the [Ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html), the difference is:

**Array#+** :

> Concatenation — Returns a new array built by concatenating the two arrays together to produce a third array.

**Array#concat** :

> Array#concat : Appends the elements of other_ary to self.

So the `+` operator will create a new array each time it is called (which is expensive), while `concat` only appends the new element.

Answer (score 19):

The answer lies in Ruby's underlying C implementation of the `+` operator and the `concat` methods.

**[`Array#+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-2B)**

```
rb_ary_plus(VALUE x, VALUE y)
{
    VALUE z;
    long len, xlen, ylen;

    y = to_ary(y);
    xlen = RARRAY_LEN(x);
    ylen = RARRAY_LEN(y);
    len = xlen + ylen;
    z = rb_ary_new2(len);

    ary_memcpy(z, 0, xlen, RARRAY_CONST_PTR(x));
    ary_memcpy(z, xlen, ylen, RARRAY_CONST_PTR(y));
    ARY_SET_LEN(z, len);
    return z;
}
```

**[`Array#concat`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-concat)**

```
rb_ary_concat(VALUE x, VALUE y)
{
    rb_ary_modify_check(x);
    y = to_ary(y);
    if (RARRAY_LEN(y) > 0) {
        rb_ary_splice(x, RARRAY_LEN(x), 0, y);
    }
    return x;
}
```

As you can see, the `+` operator is copying the memory from each array, then creating and returning a third array with the contents of both. The `concat` method is simply splicing the new array into the original one.

Comment: What about += ? Is it the same as #concat, technically?

Comment: @NoICE In Ruby, you can write operand expressions a few ways. The most relevant here is `x = x + y`, which is equivalent to `x += y`. Unless a class specifically overwrites the plus operator to delegate to `concat`, `+=` would not perform exactly the same as `concat` because it uses `rb_ary_plus` rather than `rb_ary_concat`.

Answer (score 8):

If you're going to run benchmarks, take advantage of prebuilt tools and reduce the test to the minimum necessary to test what you want to know.

Starting with [Fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity), which provides a lot of intelligence to its benchmarking:

```
require 'fruity'

compare do
  plus { [] + [4, 5] }
  concat { [].concat([4, 5]) }
end
# >> Running each test 32768 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> plus is similar to concat
```

When things are close enough to not really worry about, Fruity will tell us they're "similar".

At that point Ruby's built-in [Benchmark](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html) class can help:

```
require 'benchmark'

N = 10_000_000
3.times do
  Benchmark.bm do |b|
    b.report('plus')  { N.times { [] + [4, 5] }}
    b.report('concat') { N.times { [].concat([4,5]) }}
  end
end
# >>        user     system      total        real
# >> plus  1.610000   0.000000   1.610000 (  1.604636)
# >> concat  1.660000   0.000000   1.660000 (  1.668227)
# >>        user     system      total        real
# >> plus  1.600000   0.000000   1.600000 (  1.598551)
# >> concat  1.690000   0.000000   1.690000 (  1.682336)
# >>        user     system      total        real
# >> plus  1.590000   0.000000   1.590000 (  1.593757)
# >> concat  1.680000   0.000000   1.680000 (  1.684128)
```

Notice the different times. Running a test once can result in misleading results, so run them several times. Also, make sure your loops result in a time that isn't buried in background noise caused by processes kicking off.

Comment: Including actual performance times over only the select input is relatively misleading as it's a very small value of n that yields very 'tame' differences.

Comment: (The original tests actually show the performance difference better by 'unexpected side effect'.)

Answer (score 3):

The OP's question, as noted in other answers, is comparing two operators that perform different purposes. One, `concat`, which is destructive to (mutates) the original array, and `+` which is non-destructive (pure functional, no mutation).

I came here looking for a more comparable test, not realizing at the time, that concat was destructive.  In case it's useful to others looking to compare two purely functional, non-destructive operations, here is a benchmark of array addition (`array1 + array2`) vs array expansion (`[*array1, *array2]`).  Both, as far as I'm aware, result in 3 arrays being created: 2 input arrays, 1 new resulting array.

*Hint: `+` wins.*

**Code**

```
# a1 is a function producing a random array to avoid caching
a1 = ->(){ [rand(10)] }
a2 = [1,2,3]
n = 10_000_000
Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report('expand'){ n.times{ [*a1[], *a2] } }
  b.report('add'){ n.times{ a1[]+a2 } }
end
```

**Result**

```
user     system      total        real
expand  9.970000   0.170000  10.140000 ( 10.151718)
add  7.760000   0.020000   7.780000 (  7.792146)
```

Answer (score 2):

I did benchmark using two versions of ruby. And the result shows concat is faster than plus(+)

```
require 'benchmark'

N = 10_000_000
5.times do
  Benchmark.bm do |b|
    b.report('concat') { N.times { [].concat([4,5]) }}
    b.report('plus')  { N.times { [] + [4, 5] }}
  end
end
```

**ruby-2.5.3**

```
       user     system      total        real
concat  1.347328   0.001125   1.348453 (  1.349277)
plus  1.405046   0.000110   1.405156 (  1.405682)
       user     system      total        real
concat  1.263601   0.012012   1.275613 (  1.276105)
plus  1.336407   0.000051   1.336458 (  1.336951)
       user     system      total        real
concat  1.264517   0.019985   1.284502 (  1.285004)
plus  1.329239   0.000002   1.329241 (  1.329733)
       user     system      total        real
concat  1.347648   0.004012   1.351660 (  1.352149)
plus  1.821616   0.000034   1.821650 (  1.822307)
       user     system      total        real
concat  1.256387   0.000000   1.256387 (  1.256828)
plus  1.269306   0.007997   1.277303 (  1.277754)
```

**ruby-2.7.1**

```
       user     system      total        real
concat  1.406091   0.000476   1.406567 (  1.406721)
plus  1.295966   0.000044   1.296010 (  1.296153)
       user     system      total        real
concat  1.281295   0.000000   1.281295 (  1.281436)
plus  1.267036   0.000027   1.267063 (  1.267197)
       user     system      total        real
concat  1.291685   0.000003   1.291688 (  1.291826)
plus  1.266182   0.000000   1.266182 (  1.266320)
       user     system      total        real
concat  1.272261   0.000001   1.272262 (  1.272394)
plus  1.265784   0.000000   1.265784 (  1.265916)
       user     system      total        real
concat  1.272507   0.000001   1.272508 (  1.272646)
plus  1.294839   0.000000   1.294839 (  1.294974)
```

Memory Usage

```
require "benchmark/memory"

N = 10_000_00
Benchmark.memory do |x|
  x.report("array concat") { N.times { [].concat([4,5]) } }
  x.report("array +") { N.times { [] + [4, 5] } }

  x.compare!
end

Calculating -------------------------------------
        array concat    80.000M memsize (     0.000  retained)
                         2.000M objects (     0.000  retained)
                         0.000  strings (     0.000  retained)
             array +   120.000M memsize (     0.000  retained)
                         3.000M objects (     0.000  retained)
                         0.000  strings (     0.000  retained)

Comparison:
        array concat:   80000000 allocated
             array +:  120000000 allocated - 1.50x more
```

Comment: Good for you. But why did you add this answer? This is nothing but copy-paste of `@the Tin Man` answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23764650/4453714

Comment: @YuriiVerbytskyi The reason I answer because the answer given by Tinman was 6 years back. So, I thought I can give an updated comparison of the latest version of ruby. If there is an issue I can delete my answer

Comment: its not a problem, but it would be more useful to point the reason of this results instead of only new benchmark. The main thing is the different number of objects, created by this operations (there is 1.5x more objects creating in `plus` case):
`..times { [].concat([4,5]) }` - 2 objects created ([] and [4,5]), first returns with changes

Comment: `times { [] + [4, 5] }` here is 3rd object returned every time ([], [4,5], and `[] + [4, 5]`new object creating every iteration)

Comment: You can try to add some useful info about memory allocation, based for example on this gem https://github.com/michaelherold/benchmark-memory

Comment: @YuriiVerbytskyi  I have updated the answer with info related to memory allocation

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, in benchmarking the differences between 3 **mutating** approaches for combining arrays my benchmarks indicate that the add and reassign approach is in fact the fastest with a constant margin of approximately 1%. (with ruby 3.1.2)

Benchmark:

```
A = [4, 5].freeze
N = 10_000_000

require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report('plus  ') { N.times { c = [1, 2]; c = c + A } }
  b.report('concat') { N.times { [1, 2].concat(A) } }
  b.report('push  ') { N.times { [1, 2].push(*A) } }
end
```

Results:

```
       user     system      total        real
plus    1.180429   0.015026   1.195455 (  1.199552)
concat  1.228267   0.008172   1.236439 (  1.237004)
push    1.242709   0.007759   1.250468 (  1.251412)
```